# Python: can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Только настроил в Geany переменную Path, как вылезла новые ошибки:

```
1)Python: can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Эта ошибка почему-то выскакивает, хотя в коде ничего с файлами нет. Решил погуглить эту проблему, и Интернет посоветовал мне ввести:

```
import os
print(os.listdir("./"))
```

Или так:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

После этого посмотреть на результат, но тогда вылезла другая ошибка:

```
"-" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или файлом.
```

Заранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Как настроили переменную Path?

Comment: юзал в idle, >>> import sys,os
>>> print(os.path.dirname(sys.executable)). вывело расположение питона  (это и поставил в path)

Comment: Что конкретно у вас в path прописано?

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема в VS CODE с расширением на Пайтон, и я, кажется, её решил. У меня программный файл хранился в

```
.../python`s/
```

Я убрал апостроф, и оно пока работает, теперь программа нормально запускается из папки

```
.../pythons/
```